# Test for Time and continuous variable

Tags: time-series, continuous-data

I think this is a really basic question but would appreciate some help. I have a set of data week-by-week, with a continuous variable - the numbers of times a keyword was mentioned in the media each week. There are some weeks in the middle that are higher, and I want to see if these are significantly higher. I can't find a test that fits this basic need.

Would appreciate any help.

Comment: How many weeks do you have?

Comment: I have 13 weeks.

Comment: OK, in that case I guess you could simply run an ANOVA with week as factor with 13 levels and your outcome variable as the dependent and then (as your overall ANOVA test would likely be significant) you could run pairwise comparisons for each week pair. But I think this is not the best solution, I hope you get a better answer.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Sointu! I appreciate it

Comment: I still don't dare to put this in an answer because I don't know time series analyses, which I suspect might be the right approach, but other things you could do: 1) curvilinear regression, where you predict your outcome with week (as numeric) and week squared. Then, if the week squared coefficient is significant but week "normal" is not, you have evidence that week is related to the outcome in a curvilinear manner. 2) if it seems reasonable, recode the weeks into a 3- or 4-level categorical variable (like weeks 1-4-> 1, 5-8->2, 9-13->3) and use that as factor in ANOVA.